# How to create meaningful unit tests for fakes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, service, dependency-injection

I understand the basics on how to unit test, however I often struggle at finding what meaningful things to test. I believe I have to create a fake implementation and inject into the consumer. I have a service class responsible to subscribing to (using Exchange Web Services (EWS)) Exchange 2010 requesting updates on new mail. In order to decouple my subscribing implementation from the service itself I decided to inject the implementation in the service. Below is what I currently have. I've omitted code dealing specifically communicating with Exchange.

```
// Not a big fan of having two identical interfaces...
public interface IStreamingNotificationService
{
    void Subscribe();
}

public interface IExchangeService
{
    void Subscribe();
}

public class StreamingNotificationService : IStreamingNotificationService
{
    private readonly IExchangeService _exchangeService;

    public StreamingNotificationService(IExchangeService exchangeService)
    {
        if (exchangeService == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("exchangeService");
        }

        _exchangeService = exchangeService;
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        _exchangeService.Subscribe();
    }
}

public class ExchangeServiceImpl : IExchangeService
{
    private readonly INetworkConfiguration _networkConfiguration;
    private ExchangeService ExchangeService { get; set; }

    public ExchangeServiceImpl(INetworkConfiguration networkConfiguration)
    {
        if (networkConfiguration == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("networkConfiguration");
        }

        _networkConfiguration = networkConfiguration;
        // Set up EWS 
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        // Subscribe for new mail notifications.
    }
}
```

More specifically, how do I create a meaningful unit test to ensure subscribing works the way it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you would use a mocking framework to create a fake exchange and test on this object that Subscribe was indeed called. I usually use [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx), and your test would look e.g. like this (there are many ways to implement it):

```
[Test]
public void SubscribesToExchange()
{
  var exchange = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IExchangeService>(); //this is the stub
  var service = StreamingNotificationService(exchange); //this is the object we are testing

  service.Subscribe();
  service.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Subscribe(););
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Decoupling and injection is always a very good idea in terms of unittesting.

Now you can easily test your StreamingNotificationService class. All you have to do is to test is if construction behaves nice, and if subscribemethod calls your injected (and fake) IExchangeService.